# Passing in a variable to a custom model field

Tags: django, django-models

Is it possible to pass in values to the init of a custom model field?

Example code:

```
class Example(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    text = EncryptedCharField('Text',max_length=255)

class BaseEncryptedField(models.Field):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.cipher = AES.new(key)
        models.Field.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)            

    def to_python(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, EncryptedString):
            return self.cipher.decrypt(binascii.a2b_base64(str(value))).split(EOD)[0]
        return value

    def get_db_prep_value(self, value):
        if value is not None and not isinstance(value, EncryptedString):
            saltlength = self.cipher.block_size - (len(value) + len(EOD)) % self.cipher.block_size
            if saltlength:
               value = ''.join([value,EOD,generate_salt(saltlength)])
            value = EncryptedString(binascii.b2a_base64(self.cipher.encrypt(value)))
        return value
```

In the init function, I'd like to pass a key (which is stored in the user profile and changes depending on the user) in to set up the AES cipher, but I can't seem to figure out how to get it in.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand your problem... but here goes.

If you pass the argument to the constructor of your model (**init**), it'll be available in the "args" collection. You can also pass arguments as a map (so you can access them by name through kwargs).

So you should do something like args[0], to get your key. (Can't remember exactly if the first passed parameter is at index 0 or 1, you can always try it out/debug =))

Comment: Sorry let me be more clear. The value I want to pass in to the BaseEncryptedField is not constant, it changes depending on the user. Therefore I want to figure out a way to initialize the text field in the Example model to take, as an argument, a key from the user's profile.

Comment: something like: text = EncryptedCharField(user.key,max_length=255) ? If so, let me know and I'll update the answer.

Comment: Yeah, something like that. That line itself doesn't work though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. In class Example:

```
text = EncryptedCharField('Text', max_length=255, key=pass_the_user's_key_here)
```

Then in BaseEncryptedField.**init**:

```
self.cipher = AES.new(kwargs['key'])
```